# How can I passing partial array to left and right Gallery buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

This code works and creates a modal with a single image in it depending upon which thumbnail is clicked.

I trim away "./thumbnails/tn" and replace it with ./mypix/ to show the high res image in the modal. (Thumbnails are in a different directory with a name prefix of tn).

The 500 images have ID myImg1 .... to myImg500. But I don't want to include myImg51, myImg52, myImg53, and a few others.

How do I pass the array of images to Java and add left and right buttons to my code? I would like the user to be able to browse through the images. I don't want thumbnails on the image page as I want to maximize the view of the photograph.

And I would like it to wrap so the last image right button shows the first image.

```html
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 0px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

.modal-content {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 300px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="myImg" id="myImg1" src="./thumbnails/tnPIC012386.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="myFunctionElt(this);"><br>
<img class="myImg" id="myImg2" src="./thumbnails/tnPIC012436.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="myFunctionElt(this);"><br>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>

<script>
function myFunctionElt (elt) {
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
            span.onclick = function() { 
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    var strID = document.getElementById(elt.id);
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var str = strID.src;
    var str1 = "./mypix/";
    var str2 = str.substr(str.length - 13);
    var res = str1.concat(str2);
    modalImg.src = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: "How do I pass the array of images to Java..... " It's not Java, it's JavaScript. Small words make large differences.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets talk about getting your full set of image attributes into a data structure.  I'm going to recommend using an object instead of any array.  Mainly because we'll have some more flexibility in how to access it.

```
var images = {};

function populateImages(){
    // do stuff here to retrieve all your data about your set of images...
    // here's how to load each image into the images object... 
    var image = {
        CLASS: "myImg",
        ID: "myImg1",
        SRC: "./thumbnails/tnPIC012386.jpg",
        STYLE: "width:100%;max-width:300px",
        ONCLICK: "myFunctionElt(this);"
    };
    images[image.ID] = image;
}

populateImages();
```

Obviously the code above currently only puts a single image into the images object... its for demo purposes only... you'll need to make your calls to get the info about each image and/or hardcode all the image insertion there.  The important part is that the set of property keys inside of the images object will be the image ids.

Assuming you get the images all loaded into the images object then you can have an array of image ids for which you don't want to display thumbnails  and you can use the array.filter function to output a set of all image IDs that aren't in your excluded array

```
var excludedIDArray = [];
function populateExcludedIDs(){
    // do stuff to populate the array with the
    // set of id's for which you don't want thumbnails displayed
    excludedIDArray.push('myImg51');
    excludedIDArray.push('myImg52');
    excludedIDArray.push('myImgWhatever');
}

populateExcludedIDs();
var imageIDArray = Object.keys(images);
var thumbnailArray = imageIDArray.filter(id => !excludedIDArray.includes(id));
```

thumbnailArray is now the list of all image IDs that aren't excluded

right now you have your thumbnails hanging out as child elements of body directly...  let's move them into a div so we can use script to populate all those elements more cleanly

```
<body>
    <div id="thumbsList">
        <img class="myImg" id="myImg1" src="./thumbnails/tnPIC012386.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="myFunctionElt(this);"><br>
        <img class="myImg" id="myImg2" src="./thumbnails/tnPIC012436.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="myFunctionElt(this);"><br>
    </div>
```

Now we do a function to fill up that div with whatever is in your thumbnailArray

```
function populateThumbnails(){
    var container = document.getElementByID("thumbsList");
    container.innerHTML = '';
    for(var index = 0; index < thumbnailArray.length; index++){
        var image = images[thumbnailArray[index]];
        var imageElement = document.createElement("IMG");
        for (var key in Object.keys(image)) {
            imageElement.setAttribute(key, image[key]);
        }
        container.appendChild(imageElement);
    }
}

populateThumbnails();
```

Because of the way we stored each image in the images object...  basically each property of the images object is itself an object whose properties are the individual attributes of the resultant image tags that will be used in the HTML... we use the elements of the thumbnailsArray to find the image object within images... and then we create new img tag and loop through all the properties of the image object using each key:value pair to set the new img tag's attributes.  Then we just add the new img tag as a child of the thumbsList div.

Now, all of your thumbs should be showing up and you can open your modal with any of them...

Before we tackle the left and right buttons,lets change up the way we call myFunctionElt...  rather than passing in the full (this) from the img tags, let's just pass in (this.id):

```
<img class="myImg" id="myImg1" src="./thumbnails/tnPIC012386.jpg" style="width:100%;max-width:300px" onclick="myFunctionElt(this.id);">
```

Now, let's adjust MyFunctionElt to handle the fact that its only getting the ID and then add the setting of the current image index

```
// create a variable to hold the index within thumbnailArray
// of the selected image
var modalImageIndex = 0;

function myFunctionElt (eltID) {
    // set modalImageIndex
    modalImageIndex = thumbnailArray.indexOf(eltID);

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    var strID = document.getElementById(eltID);
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    var str = strID.src;
    var str1 = "./mypix/";
    var str2 = str.substr(str.length - 13);
    var res = str1.concat(str2);
    modalImg.src = res;
}
```

Now we should be all set to go for the last little bit...  lets add buttons to your modal template for left and right.  You'll obviously want to style them however you want, what I have here will be plain and not aligned very visually pleasing.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <button id="shiftLeft" onclick="shiftImage('PREVIOUS')">Previous</button>
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <button id="shiftRight" onclick="shiftImage('NEXT')">Next</button>
</div>
```

So, we have 2 buttons, Previous and Next... they both call a function called shiftImage() and pass in a text string... so lets define that function

```
function shiftImage(direction){
    switch(direction){
        case 'PREVIOUS':
            if(modalImageIndex == 0){
              modalImageIndex = thumbnailArray.length;
            }
            modalImageIndex--;
            break;
        case 'NEXT':
            modalImageIndex++;
            modalImageIndex = modalImageIndex % thumbnailArray.length;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    myFunctionElt(thumbnailArray[modalImageIndex]);
}
```

So in the shiftImage function, we either increment or decrement modalImageIndex value.  If the result is less than 0 then we set it to be the end of the thumbnailArray.. To handle the end case, we use the modulus operator to cycle it back to the beginning.  Once we update the modalImageIndex value, then we call your myFunctionElt function and pass in the imageID of the newly indexed value in thumbnailArray.

At this point you should have all the moving pieces... it'll just be up to you to arrange them in your code appropriately, make adjustments to styling, and actually add the code to populate the images object and excludedIDArray

Typically questions of this nature are too broad for asking on stackOverflow... but I was bored this morning lol... cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much. I coded the buttons and sorted it out. I have been trying to get this to work for some time. One small question. My Dreamweaver gives me a syntax error on the line ------ var thumbnailArray = imageIDArray.filter(id => !excludedIDArray.includes(id)); --- Any idea why? It works anyway so maybe it's just Dreamweaver misbehaving.

Comment: not sure... my guess would be that depending on the version of Dreamweaver you're using, it might not fully support ES6, so the arrow function may be throwing it off, or maybe it wants the arrow function to actually do a return statement or something...  but that's just a shot in the dark

Comment: if it bugs you, you could swap it out for pre ES6 syntax:  var thumbnailArray = imageIDArray.filter(function(id){return !excludedIDArray.includes(id);});

Comment: Thanks. Incredible effort much appreciated. Now I am running it in testmode I have found a small incompatibility error with some pre existing Javascript. Trying to isolate the problem I discovered everything works if I comment out the line "populateThumbnails();" Following the logic I find i strange it works without that. This is a demo with the line commented out. http://www.garryjones.se/phototest/working.html  - This is a demo with the line still live. http://www.garryjones.se/phototest/notworking.html  Any idea? As it's working can I just go without that line?

Comment: So... I looked at your page source... the reason it doesnt work is because my solution above just puts a ton of image tags into a div with id="thumbList".  You didnt go that route (which is fine)... but beause you didnt, the code in populateThumbnails (1 doesnt need to run because you are manually putting the img tags in your markup and 2, is fails because the var container comes back undefined and then the code tries to access attributes of undefined.   You can just kill off the populateThumbnails function and the call to it

Comment: An additional note, in your populateImages() you just copied and pasted my code multiple times... so you have var image =   several times...  some javascript engines will error out on var redeclarations...    the first time var image = {} is fine.. after that just drop var and leave it as image = {};

Comment: Thanks. I tested a few possibilities and I'm grasping the basics of Javascript. My next task is to move those green and red buttons to the full window modal box and overlay it. I tried but couldn't get the modal content to change. I left it as it was. I'd appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. I removed the "populateThumbnails" section. You have been very helpful already so I'll understand if you just tell me to read a manual. :) Thanks again for everything, most helpful. 

http://www.garryjones.se/phototest/working.html

Comment: While not telling you to "go read a manual", if you are just getting into javascript, the code academy intro course is very good.. and free.  https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript as for your modal, im not much of a web designer so cant say how best to design it... but you'll need to edit the html of of what's in your div with id='myModal'.   Just like you added the left and right buttons.

Comment: The issue is that your buttons under the thumbnails have hard coded in information into the tags, and that wont work with your modal because the same set of buttons is used for different pictures.   I recommend not using input tags and just make them buttons.  give the button tags an onclick="setRating('<insert rating here>')" attribute... each button would substitute DELETE, BAD, GOOD etc for <insert rating here>.  When you define the setRating function it can reference the modalImageIndex variable to know for what img the button was clicked

Comment: The alternative is that you'd have to modify your myFunctionElt function to delete the buttons from the modal div and then re-create them using values for the new image...  you can look at the populateThumbnails() function code to see how that might work